# skrollr Animation frames before page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, html, skrollr

I am encountering very strange behavior, that I can't explain on a site I'm building (http://kijani.co). The page load is delayed extremely through countless Animation frames that are fired with Function Call: /js/skrollr.min.js:2. This goes on for 30 seconds, before the actual page is loaded. I use skrollr for paralax scrolling, the site is hand coded (source code on https://github.com/MrLoh/kijani).

skrollr is supposed to be initalized on document ready. I have no idea what is going on and can't find anything on the web.

Comment: Screenshot from the chrome dev-panel: 25s idle??  http://cl.ly/image/2v1Z0L0F473S

Comment: I think I just solved the Problem. The pagespeed optimization function of dream host somehow caused the issue. I am not sure how, but turning off this feature resolved the issue. The page is now loading properly just like on the local server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the pagespeed optimization function of dream host somehow caused the issue. I am not sure how, but turning off this feature resolves the issue.